# How to store sql DEFAULT timestamp in a preferred format?

Tags: java, mysql

Actually I searched and found some related topics but none satisfies my need; So this is why I'm asking this question. Hope someone can help:

I'm writing to MySQL tables in java; One column is timestamp and I want to store the timestamp  in it the way I want, which is this:

```
09 May 2016 14:20:13 UTC
```

,exactly like this.

Actually I can get some part in mysql with this command:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( unix_timestamp() ),'%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s' );
```

but I don't know how to put it in my java and then store it to my timestamp column.

Could somebody help?

Thanks in advance,
Paay

Comment: The Date will not store the format.  Try using SimpleDateFormet

Comment: Dates don't have a format, they are values on a timeline. Format is something applied when displaying the date value. I don't think there is *any* RDBMS that preserves formatting on date/timestamp columns.